# Ubuntu 17.10.1 boot hangs on older Dell laptop

Tags: boot, 17.10

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10.1 on an old Dell E6500 laptop.  When I attempt to boot it reports

```
/dev/sda2: clean, x files, x blocks
```

and then hangs.

Looking at kern.log I find ... (see the last 6 lines)

```
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.130869] kvm: disabled by bios
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.148816] yenta_cardbus 0000:03:01.0: ISA IRQ mask 0x0cb8, PCI irq 19
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.148818] yenta_cardbus 0000:03:01.0: Socket status: 30000006
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.148822] pci_bus 0000:03: Raising subordinate bus# of parent bus (#03) from #04 to #07
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.148829] yenta_cardbus 0000:03:01.0: pcmcia: parent PCI bridge window: [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.148831] yenta_cardbus 0000:03:01.0: pcmcia: parent PCI bridge window: [mem 0xf1b00000-0xf1bfffff]
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.148833] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xf1b00000-0xf1bfffff:
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.148839]  excluding 0xf1bf0000-0xf1bfffff
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.165823] kvm: disabled by bios
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.200889] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.200997] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.201030] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.273956] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.347103] dell_wmi: Detected Dell WMI interface version 1
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.347112] dell_wmi: firmware scancode 0x200 maps to unrecognized keycode 0xffff
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.347162] input: Dell WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/PNP0C14:00/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00/9DBB5994-A997-11DA-B012-B622A1EF5492/input/input12
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.522468] dell_laptop: Using i8042 filter function for receiving events
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.637051] leds dell::kbd_backlight: Setting an LED's brightness failed (-5)
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690685] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0x0c0000-0x0fffff:
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690694]  excluding 0xc0000-0xd3fff 0xe0000-0xfffff
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690721] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xa0000000-0xa0ffffff:
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690733]  excluding 0xa0000000-0xa0ffffff
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690753] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0x60000000-0x60ffffff:
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690765]  excluding 0x60000000-0x60ffffff
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.697968] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: changing MTU from 1500 to 576
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.777401] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.824780] gpio_ich: GPIO from 435 to 495 on gpio_ich
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.851799] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.884282] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   12.224405] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: changing MTU from 576 to 1500
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   12.811149] Adding 19530748k swap on /dev/sda1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:19530748k FS
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   13.137812] audit: type=1400 audit(1520105425.450:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=412 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   13.174540] audit: type=1400 audit(1520105425.487:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=410 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   13.174543] audit: type=1400 audit(1520105425.487:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=410 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   13.174545] audit: type=1400 audit(1520105425.487:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=410 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   13.174548] audit: type=1400 audit(1520105425.487:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=410 comm="apparmor_parser"

##### The next 6 lines repeat every 2 seconds, forever #####
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   14.108901] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   14.109009] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   14.109041] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   14.113152] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: changing MTU from 1500 to 576
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   14.193505] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
Mar  3 12:30:27 helios kernel: [   15.139210] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: changing MTU from 576 to 1500
```

Meanwhile syslog shows ... (see the last 11 lines)

```
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.522468] dell_laptop: Using i8042 filter function for receiving events
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.637051] leds dell::kbd_backlight: Setting an LED's brightness failed (-5)
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690685] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0x0c0000-0x0fffff:
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690694]  excluding 0xc0000-0xd3fff 0xe0000-0xfffff
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690721] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xa0000000-0xa0ffffff:
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690733]  excluding 0xa0000000-0xa0ffffff
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690753] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0x60000000-0x60ffffff:
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.690765]  excluding 0x60000000-0x60ffffff
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.697968] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: changing MTU from 1500 to 576
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.777401] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.824780] gpio_ich: GPIO from 435 to 495 on gpio_ich
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.851799] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   11.884282] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   12.224405] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: changing MTU from 576 to 1500
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   12.811149] Adding 19530748k swap on /dev/sda1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:19530748k FS
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   13.137812] audit: type=1400 audit(1520105425.450:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/
usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=412 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   13.174540] audit: type=1400 audit(1520105425.487:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/
sbin/dhclient" pid=410 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   13.174543] audit: type=1400 audit(1520105425.487:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/
usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=410 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   13.174545] audit: type=1400 audit(1520105425.487:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/
usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=410 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   13.174548] audit: type=1400 audit(1520105425.487:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/
usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=410 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   14.108901] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   14.109009] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   14.109041] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   14.113152] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: changing MTU from 1500 to 576
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios kernel: [   14.193505] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios grub-common[417]:    ...done.
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios systemd[1]: Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
Mar  3 12:30:26 helios systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Mar  3 12:30:27 helios accounts-daemon[428]: started daemon version 0.6.42
Mar  3 12:30:27 helios systemd[1]: Started Accounts Service.
Mar  3 12:30:27 helios systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
Mar  3 12:30:27 helios systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Mar  3 12:30:27 helios systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Mar  3 12:30:27 helios systemd[1]: Startup finished in 5.210s (kernel) + 9.554s (userspace) = 14.764s.
Mar  3 12:30:27 helios set-cpufreq[416]: Setting ondemand scheduler for all CPUs
Mar  3 12:30:27 helios systemd-networkd[271]: enp0s25: Lost carrier
Mar  3 12:30:27 helios kernel: [   15.139210] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: changing MTU from 576 to 1500
Mar  3 12:30:27 helios systemd-networkd[271]: enp0s25: DHCP lease lost

##### The following 11 messages repeat every 2 seconds, forever #####
Mar  3 12:30:29 helios systemd-networkd[271]: enp0s25: Gained carrier
Mar  3 12:30:29 helios kernel: [   17.089197] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Mar  3 12:30:29 helios kernel: [   17.089316] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
Mar  3 12:30:29 helios kernel: [   17.089384] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
Mar  3 12:30:29 helios systemd-networkd[271]: enp0s25: DHCPv4 address 192.168.1.102/24 via 192.168.1.1
Mar  3 12:30:29 helios kernel: [   17.098078] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: changing MTU from 1500 to 576
Mar  3 12:30:29 helios kernel: [   17.183259] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
Mar  3 12:30:29 helios systemd-timesyncd[300]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Mar  3 12:30:30 helios systemd-networkd[271]: enp0s25: Lost carrier
Mar  3 12:30:30 helios systemd-networkd[271]: enp0s25: DHCP lease lost
Mar  3 12:30:30 helios kernel: [   18.113752] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: changing MTU from 576 to 1500
```

It looks like there's a network problem, yet I just installed
17.10.1 from the netboot mini.iso, and the network seemed
fine then.  I'm using a hard-wired ethernet.

If I press Esc during boot and boot the recovery mode,
after many messages I get a Recovery Menu.  There I select
"resume normal boot", and the boot completes successfully,
and I can login.  However it's command line only,
and there's no startx or gdm or other way (that I know of)
to start X.

How can I get this to boot?  Thank you!

Comment: can you include the output from `journalctl -b | grep -i error`?

Comment: what does "hang" mean? From the logs it's evident, that the system is starting (correctly?). systemd is even saying "Reached target Multi-User System". What do you see on screen? If you do (CTLR-)ALT-Fx (that is press CTRL-ALT- (with or without CTRL) and any of the F1, F2, etc. keys) does that bring to to a terminal with a login or logs or such?

Comment: When the boot is done there is a single message on the screen:

Comment: When the boot is done there is a single message on the screen: "/dev/sda2: clean, 58601/44572672 files, 3409564/718260480 blocks".  That is the ONLY thing displayed!  Testing ctl-alt-f1 through f6 finds a working login prompt using tty1 through tty6.  Testing ctl-alt-f7  shows the above "clean" message.  Testing ctl-alt-f8 through f12 don't seem to do anything.    Logging in to tty6, it's clear there's no network.  So I guess the questions are, why didn't X start, and what happened to the network?

Comment: Hi  Tomáš, Thank you for your comments.  I decided to quit fighting Ubuntu and installed Linux Mint.  It works -- both the X server and network are working.  I have no idea why Ubuntu didn't.  If you'd like to propose your comment as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.  Thanks!